# No fetch Python plugins in qgis 1.8 + ubuntu 13.04

Tags: qgis, installation

I tried to install qgis 1.8 to ubuntu 13.04 but when installation finished I couldn't find "Fetch python plugin" button in plugin menu. I didn't find any soloution for this problem. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Which repositories are you using? Did you have a previous version installed?

Comment: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu raring main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu raring main


from PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable